# Fulfilment module and Supplier/Vendor product code

Tags: e-commerce, virtocommerce

The **Fulfillment** module in Commerce Manager is a great feature to replenish stock by our Fulfillment Centre who shouldn't have knowledge about the Catalog.

However we are facing a problem here. After we have placed orders to our Suppliers/Vendors to replenish our stocks, our Vendors will deliver the products we ordered directly to our Fulfillment Centre. Each of the products is labelled with the Vendor's Product Code, not our Item Code. In order to create a Receive Inventory List, Item/SKU can only be searched using Item Name and Item Code. How would our Fulfillment Centre knows which of the Vendor's Product Code corresponds to our Item Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. There are couple ways to accomplish this. You can simply prefix or postfix the Item Code with a vendor code which you can then search in the fulfillment module or you can extend fulfillment module to allow searching by custom meta field.